# What's the USD/TRY rate in 1961?

Tags: currency, historical-data

I can't find this information anywhere on the internet. Help

Earliest data I found is in 1990

I'm looking for 1961 average or a specific month or day. I'll accept any kind of data. Thanks

Comment: https://madeinturkeytours.com/turkish-lira/ is all I've found so far (back to 1970). I'm sure you've looked at the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_lira#First_Turkish_lira_(1923%E2%80%932005) which also gives sourced older data via https://fxtop.com/en/historical-exchange-rates.php?A=1&C1=USD&C2=TRL&YA=1&DD1=01&MM1=01&YYYY1=1953&B=1&P=&I=1&DD2=06&MM2=02&YYYY2=2020&btnOK=Go%21 which should answer your question

Comment: If you visit books.google.com and search for `turkish lira pegged to dollar` (without quotes) several sources seem to indicate the Turkish lira was pegged to the dollar in 1961